# Why な instead of の is used in the anime title "はるかなレシーブ"?

Tags: particles, particle-の, particle-な

There is an anime named "はるかなレシーブ" this season. While the [official English name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harukana_Receive) is just using the Romaji (i.e. Harukana Receive) instead of translating the meaning, from the [Chinese official translation](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%81%99%E7%9A%84%E6%8E%A5%E7%90%83), it seems that the name of the anime means "Haruka's Receive". As the main character is named Ozora Haruka, I guess this translation is correct?

If that's the correct meaning, then my question will be why な instead of の is used to connect the 2 nouns? (i.e. why "はるかなレシーブ" but not "はるかのレシーブ"?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you base your argument on the Chinese translation in the first place?  Translation is a translation.

> 「はるかなレシーブ」= 「はる」+「かな」+「レシーブ」
>
> 「はるかなレシーブ」≠ 「はるか」+「な」+「レシーブ」

That is because the names of the two main characters are:

大空{おおぞら} 遥{はるか}

and

比嘉{ひが} かなた

That is 「**はる**か」 and 「**かな**た」.

Thus, 「はるかな」= 「はる」+「かな」

There never was a reason to name the story 「はるか**の**レシーブ」.

Comment: to be fair to the poster, unless you're aware that this kind of "name conflation" is sometimes done (we do it in English too, sometimes) and unless you knew off the top of your head that the other main character's name was something beginning with かな, a beginner in Japanese might naturally assume that there was a play on words going on, with only that one character's name.  Had her name been はるこ、はるあ or anything but はるか, it might have been more obvious.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I refer to the translation because I don't understand what it means in Japanese, and dictionary don't tell what is "はるかな". (and choosing Chinese because it is my mother language) However, I understand translation may not be directly reflecting the meaning in Japanese, that's why my first question is if the translation is showing the Japanese meaning. With that consideration in mind, I think using translation as a reference is not that bad?

Comment: If the Chinese translation is actually "Haruka's Receive" then that's a bad translation and the fault lies there.

Comment: It could also have been a choice to give it a name that wasn't a direct translation, which happens frequently in other cases (e.g. almost every Disney film's Japanese title, many Ghibli films' English titles).